# PS Now game save transfer

Tags: ps4, borderlands, ps-now

I am trying out PS Now, while I like it I don't think I'll keep it for more then 2 months. I never played borderlands but it aged well and is really really fun, don't want to lose any of my progress.

Is it possible to transfer saves from Borderlands PS Now to the PS4 version once I buy it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But to do it you need an active PS+ subscription.

> To download the save back to your PS4 local storage, follow the process below.
>
> - Press the PS Button and choose [Application Saved Data Management] > [Saved Data in System Storage] > [Upload to Online Storage].
> - Select the game data you would like to save & click Upload
> - Close the Application Saved Data Management on the PS4.
> - The file can now be downloaded from your PS Plus storage to your PS4.

[Source](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/services/playstation-now/how-to-transfer-game-progress-between-playstation-now-and-playst/).